# What type of regression for qualitative dependent variable

Tags: regression, econometrics, least-squares, qualitative

What econometric analysis can be used to study the impact of quantitative independent variables on a qualitative dependent variable? Basically, how do I do conduct a multiple variable regression where the Y variable is qualitative? Please suggest readings/helpful links if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: While you can fit models suitable for categorical or ordered-categorical  responses (what I assume you mean by qualitative DV), they would not normally be fitted by OLS.

Answer (score 5):

You use a method designed for the type of Y variable you have.  If it is a dichotomy, then logistic regression is a place to start.  If ordinal, ordinal logistic regression; if nominal, multinomial logistic.

Answer (score 1):

According to Gujarati (2007) the most appropriate econometric method to be used for a study in which the dependent variable is qualitatively captured is qualitative response regression model (probit, tobit, logit [multinomial logit, ordinal logit and nested logit).

Comment: Can you edit to include a proper reference for the article or book you cite?